# How to load xcrysden GUI in OSX after installing through Macports?

Tags: quantum-espresso, visualization-software, apple-operating-system

I am using MacOS Ventura, and would like to use xcrysden to visualize my Quantum espresso input and output files. For that, I have installed xcrysden on using Macports. But I am not able to laod the xcrysden GUI using a command like:
`xcrysden --pwi si.0_scf.in`. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you load the GUI directly instead of loading a file?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not. Something like "xcrysden -h" initiates xcrysden on terminal, but does not start the GUI.

Comment: How about the command `xcrysden` only without the `-h`? What type of error does it give? Please add the detail of the terminal output/error after you run the `xcrysden` command on terminal

Comment: I get this: 

+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|*****************************************************************|
|*                                                               *|
|*  XCrySDen -- (X-Window) CRYstalline Structures and DENsities  *|
...
  Version: 1.6.2

  Please report bugs to: ...


  TERMS OF USE:
  -------------
  XCRYSDEN is ... Public License.

  Whenever ...  is the following:

  [ref] ...

XCRYSDEN_TOPDIR=/opt/local/share/xcrysden-1.6.2
XCRYSDEN_SCRATCH=/var/folders/tz/wqzs1wbj2cd30c7z3p3vm0rh0000gn/T/

Comment: I had to cut down many of the texts, but I got something like that. The GUI does not pop up, unfortunately.

Comment: These are the expected output in the terminals when you run xcrysden. So the problem is only the GUI being not opened. Unfortunately I cannot help you on that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments though!